# Is there any difference using quotes on defining a variable or not?

Tags: twig

The Twig manual ("[include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)") says this:

```
{% include 'foo' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

But this works fine too:

```
{% include 'foo' with { foo: 'bar'} %}
```

So is there any difference or are the quotes arbitrary?

Comment: If you see something done a certain way in the documentation, then chances are it is necessary for proper syntax and you should not deviate from that syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer by @Maerlyn is not completely accurate.

As of Twig 1.5 you can use unquoted strings as the key name in hashes. For example `{foo: 'bar'}` is the same as `{'foo': 'bar'}` even if you had a variable named `foo` in your template it would not clash with the hash key name of `foo`. It's a convenience thing, that's all.

**For example:**

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
{% set bar = {foo: foo} %} {# note: no quotes around foo #}
{% debug bar %}
```

**Expected output:**

```
array
  'foo' => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't make any difference at all, like I thought in the beginning. Thanks.